# Writing to an SQL table on order completion

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I recently migrated my Wordpress website to a hosting server and have had issues getting one function to work. When testing it on my local server it worked perfectly but now I can't seem to figure out why it will not write to my SQL table. The function is here below, any help will be very appreciated. I was also wondering if there is a way to only have the SQL query run when I receive the payment from PayPal if it would require a large change to this program it is not an issue.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'checkout_custom_table_insert', 20, 4 );
function checkout_custom_table_insert( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){

// Only for 'processing' and 'completed' order status changes
$statuses = array( 'processing', 'completed' );
if ( ! in_array( $new_status, $statuses ) ) return;

// Check if data has been already updated (avoid repetitions)
$is_done = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_checkout_table_updated', true );
if( ! empty($is_done) ) return; // We exit if it has been already done

global $wpdb;

// Loop through order items
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item){
    $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the variation product object

    // Choose in the array which data you want to insert (each line is a table column)
    $args = array(
        'rank'          => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_rank' ),
        'money'         => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_money' ),
        'spawner'       => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_spawner' ),
        'permission'    => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_permission' ),
        'kit'           => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_kit' ),
        'crate'         => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_crate' ),
        'stag'          => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_stag' ),
        'duration'      => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_duration' ),
        'end_date'      => date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$duration Months")),
        'username'      => get_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', true ),
        'executed'      => "false",
    );

    // The SQL INSERT query
    $table = "checkout"; // or "{$wpdb->prefix}checkout";
    $wpdb->insert(  $table, $args ); // Insert the data
}

// Mark this task as done for this order
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_checkout_table_updated', '1' );
}
```

Comment: Are the order status changed to processing after payment? or they still remain in pending payment status in backend? Sometime the order status will stuck to pending payment status.

Comment: mysql and sql server both are diffrent, use anyone

Comment: @Yamu I have noticed issues with it staying at pending status but as of right now I am manually forcing the update. The issue is that although WooCommerce sees the order it will not write to my custom table that is in the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, you have order status as below to check against order status:

```
$statuses = array( 'processing', 'completed' );
```

but woocommerce order status are as follow:

```
'wc-pending','wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' ,'wc-completed'  , 'wc-cancelled', 'wc-refunded' , 'wc-failed'
```

update your array to:

```
$statuses = array( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' );
```

Comment: I attempted updating the array to that but it still did not write to the SQL table

Comment: Try $table = "{$wpdb->prefix}checkout"; instead of $table = "checkout"; // or "{$wpdb->prefix}checkout";

Comment: Check to see if there are any error by enabling debug and debug log in config file.

Comment: So I turned on debug to check things out but there were no errors related to the function that is supposed to write to the SQL table

Comment: It appears that the program was running the return in the "if( ! empty($is_done) ) return;" line. Any ideas why it would be doing that?

Comment: add another check for $is_done as below: (the $is_done might be returning 0 or empty array instead of '')

 if(  ! empty($is_done) && ( '1' == $is_done ) )

Comment: From what I can tell the issue is actually that the post meta updates and says the checkout table has been updated, but when I check the checkout table it's still empty